# Images to Video using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a root folder /train_images which have subfolders like /train_images/1 ,/train_images/2...etc. Ech of the subfolders have images in it. I want to make videos corresponding to each subfolder if num(images)>4. Below is the code which I wrote for the same. it works if there is only 1 subfolder,and stops at the creation of 2nd Videowriter object. Please help

```
import cv2
import os

root_folder = 'train_images'
video_folder = 'output_video'
folders = [folder for folder in os.listdir(root_folder)]
for folder in folders:
 child = os.path.join(root_folder,folder)
 images = [img for img in os.listdir(child) if img.endswith(".jpg")]
 print('%d images in the path %s' % (len(images),child))
 if(len(images)>=4):
    video_path ='{}.avi'.format(folder)
    print(video_path)
    print(os.path.join(video_folder, video_path))
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join(video_folder, video_path), -1, 5, (224, 320))
    for img in images:
     frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(child, img))
     print('writing from %s' %(os.path.join(child, img)) )
     frame_new=cv2.resize(frame,(224,320))
     #print(frame_new.shape)
     video.write(frame_new)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what happens. Does the script stop executing (breaking out of the for loop) or is there an error? If there is an error, what's the traceback?

Comment: I have changed the videowriter fourcc to 'MJPG' and now it works..